# How to get only one shared array in all my classes?

Tags: c++

This is my code of a example program. The problem im getting is that when I add a new item to the `shoppingCart` array, it makes a new copy of the `shoppingCart` array with the present `shoppingindex`. How can I add all these items into the same `shoppingCart` array.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;



class Product{
    private:
    protected:
        static int shoppingindex;
        string shoppingcart[10];

    public:

        Product()
        {

        }

        void displayShoppingCart() const

        {
            cout << endl<<endl;
            cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
            cout << "                                  Shopping Cart                                     \n";
            cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
//              if(shoppingcart[i].length()<=1)
//              {
//                  
//              }
//              else
                {
                    cout << "\nShopping Item " <<"("<< i+1 << ")" << " - " << shoppingcart[i]  << endl;
                    //cout << shoppingindex << endl;
                }


            }
        }
};

class DairyProduct:public Product{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
        DairyProduct()
        {

        }

        void AddDairyProduct(string productName)
        {
            shoppingcart[shoppingindex]=productName;
            shoppingindex++;


        }

};

class Beverages:public Product{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
        Beverage()
        {

        }

        void AddBeverage(string productName)
        {
            shoppingcart[shoppingindex]=productName;
            shoppingindex++;

        }

};

class PersonalCare:public Product{
    private:
    protected:
    public:
        PersonalCare()
        {

        }

        void AddPersonalCare(string productName)
        {
            //if conditions in all of them to match with the given dataset
            shoppingcart[shoppingindex]=productName;
            shoppingindex++;

        }

};

class ShoppingCart{

    public:
        Product *object;
        DairyProduct *dairy;
        Beverages *bevg;
        PersonalCare *personal;

    ShoppingCart()
    {

        object = new Product;       //deep copy
        dairy=new DairyProduct;
        bevg=new Beverages;
        personal = new PersonalCare;
    }

    ~ShoppingCart()
    {

    }
};

int Product::shoppingindex=0;

int main()
{
    ShoppingCart user;
    user.bevg->AddBeverage("Tea");
    user.bevg->displayShoppingCart();

    user.personal->AddPersonalCare("Shampoo");
    user.personal->displayShoppingCart();

    user.dairy->AddDairyProduct("Milk");
    user.dairy->displayShoppingCart();



}
```

Comment: That's a ton of code, please compress it down to a [mcve].

Comment: I have minimized the code, it can not be minimized more.

Comment: The `Product` class should not have the array. The `ShoppingCart` class should. Rethink your design. (And consider using `std::vector` instead of array.)

Comment: This code's structure makes no sense. `shoppingcart` and `shoppingindex` are members of `Product`, for some reason. `shoppingindex` is static, but `shoppingcart` isn't. `shoppingcart` isn't a `ShoppingCart`. Instances of these classes don't actually represent what their names say; for example, a `DairyProduct` has no state related to representing a dairy product, and a `ShoppingCart` isn't responsible for representing the state of a shopping cart.

Comment: You've misunderstood what a class is. `DairyProduct` isn't just where you put the functions related to dairy products; a `DairyProduct` instance should be a representation of a dairy product.

Comment: *How can I add all these items into the same shoppingCart array.* -- Wouldn't it be the same way you set up `shoppingindex`?

Comment: Im unable to do so... Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved -- Not withstanding the obvious issues with your design, I will repeat the first few words of your question:  *How to get only one shared...* -- You only have one "shared" `shoppingindex`, so how would you get only one shared array?  Do you understand what `static` means in the context of a class variable?

Comment: Got you @PaulMcKenzie, After declaring the array static, my shopping cart works fine. 
Secondly, these functions were mentioned in the required question I am solving. Thankyou all!

Comment: Is the expected output "Tea" then "Tea, Milk" then "Tea, Milk, Shampoo"? Do the different categories (dairy, beverage, personal) have any specific function, meaning do you need to be able to make a list of all the beverages, or can we just ditch those? Is milk not a beverage? Should I comment on obvious memory leaks not really related to this question?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved why do you need so many sequential empty lines in code?

Comment: i see new's but no deletes.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes

Comment: @DanielCollier association.

Comment: @Lashane not finalized yet.